# Prestashop 1.5 - cannot over ride top menu css

Tags: css, prestashop

I am new to Presta Shop and trying to create a custom theme. I have read about the documented way to do this by extending the current module css/template files where necessary here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors

It all seems straight forward. I have over rode the templates and CSS for 2 modules so far with ease but on my 3rd attempt I am encountering some issues.  I attempted to over ride the following CSS file:

```
/modules/blocktopmenu/css/superfish-modified.css
```

with this

```
/themes/newtheme/css/blocktopmenu/superfish-modified.css
```

but it did not work. Out of interest I also tried overwriting with this path too:

```
/themes/newtheme/css/blocktopmenu/blocktopmenu.css
```

but that also did not work?

Hopefully someone out there can help or shed some light as to the reason for this or a solution?

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 3):

Actually I just figured out the issue, the superfish-modified.css is in its own css folder in the actually module so the correct path to over ride should be:

```
/themes/newtheme/css/blocktopmenu/css/superfish-modified.css
```

10 points to me.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a missing "modules" in that path? Is it not…

/themes/newtheme/css/modules/blocktopmenu/css/superfish-modified.css

Answer (score 0):

to me, should be

/themes/newtheme/modules/blocktopmenu/css/superfish-modified.css

and you must copy blocktopmenu from /modules to /themes/newtheme/modules/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue related to this module. [Here the solution](http://nemops.com/editing-prestashop-top-menu/)